# "backdrop-filter: blur(10px)" is not working only with my placeholder

Tags: html, css

[blur not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXMxW.png)

Here my code

```
/* header */

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  color: var(--font-color);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px); //the line who is not working only with placerholder 
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 3cm;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 4px 0 rgb(26 26 26 / 8%), 0 4px 8px 0 rgb(26 26 26 / 12%);
}
```

So the placeholder is sense to be blur too.

Comment: please add more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

For i see its working properly ... except by this 'EX: FR2...' 'overflowing' the header, if this is from your page and not later of capturing the print .. check this element z-index property . Or if that is an SVG oO

Read about [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter#formal_definition)

*For compatibility with Safari you have to declare vendor prefix*  **-webkit-** :

`-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);`